# How much should the disk/wheel spin for gyroscopic-precession to take place? Is there a threshold?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, torque, gyroscopes

Suppose we have a spinning gyroscope whose disk is of mass $m$, spinning at angular velocity $\omega$, and attached to a rod of length $r$.

[image]

The precession of the gyroscope around the $z$-axis will be given by

$$ \frac{d\phi}{dt} = \frac{mgr}{I\omega} $$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the disk.

Now what I'm wondering is, if we send $\omega\rightarrow 0^{+}$, doesn't the precession rate go $\rightarrow +\infty$? This is clearly unphysical, so there has to be a limited domain of validity to this equation.

Clearly if take a bicycle wheel attached to a rod and hang it off a rope, it's not going to avoid falling if $\omega$ were some small but nonzero quantity (imagine $\omega = 0.1\,\textrm{s}^{-1}$), yet all introductory materials covering this topic fail to acknowledge this or take this into account.

My questions are, what is this domain of validity to the equation? Is there some sort of threshold for which precession takes place? How can we derive this threshold and what happens when this threshold is not met?

Comment: The actual motion is much more complicated than simple horizontal precession.  See, for example, here:  https://www.if.ufrj.br/~marta/caronte-hipertexto/movimentosdaterra/butikov.pdf for some nice pictures of the up-and-down motion ("nutation") that also occurs.  As $\omega\rightarrow 0$, the nutation smoothly becomes just free spherical pendulum motion.

Comment: Look also here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543313/lagrangian-of-a-precessing-wheel-gyroscope-in-lagrangian-mechanics

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is approximately valid only for fast rotators, i.e. if $I\omega^{2}\gg mgr$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).